# Auto restart iOS app for enterprise, not jailbroken

Tags: ios, objective-c, service

I'm currently developing an app using enterprise account for internal purposes only.
I heard something about daemon for jailbroken devices in order to make my app just like an android service.

Is there anything I can do when not jailbroken?
Maybe 3rd party framework or piece of codes? Maybe private framework?

Something like this maybe: [Make the application restart by itself on a jailbroken device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652297/make-the-application-restart-by-itself-on-a-jailbroken-device)
But for non-jailbroken.

P.S. - The app of course is not for app store and could not be on app store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the device is jail broken the short answer is no.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Tander. But we have achieved almost similar effect using combination of SLC (Significant Location Change), Background fetch and Silent push notifications. Whole point is that app periodically trigger call to API to let know it is alive.

If this fails, we sent normal Push Notification. I was looking into this for fair amount of time and didn't come up with nothing better. But note that you get very limited process time to execute code using this options.