# How to minimize an ios app

Tags: ios, multitasking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Force app to close and run in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8920844/force-app-to-close-and-run-in-background)

I'm creating an radio application in ios. There is a minimize button in my application. So what I want to do is when user press that button the application should be run in the background and the app icon should be displayed in the notification area like normal `Android` radio app. I want to know is it possible in `iOS` and how can I do that. Any one can show me an example.

Thanks

Comment: It would help if you shared what you have tried or researched so far, and what is not working.

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals is that a standard sentence. he cannot be succesful, because it is not possible

Comment: @AlexWien a template may be..

Comment: You WILL be rejected for doing this.

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals  I tryied only the exit(0). thant the only thing I knw to remove the app from the screen :)

Comment: Why not just press the "Home" button. Adding a button in the app really does not serve a purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to make ones application goes to background programatically is to open another app (Safari) calling its URL. But I don't think that is what you have in mind (since you are saying you have a radio app).

So if you want to imitate the same action which happens when user pressing home button, it is not possible with iOS SDK. From iOS human interface guildelines

> **Don’t Quit Programmatically**
>
> Never quit an iOS application programmatically because people tend to
>   interpret this as a crash. However, if external circumstances prevent
>   your application from functioning as intended, you need to tell your
>   users about the situation and explain what they can do about it.

Apple also says in the documentation

> People, not applications, should initiate and control actions.
>   Although an application can suggest a course of action or warn about
>   dangerous consequences, it’s usually a mistake for the app to take
>   decision-making away from the user. The best apps find the correct
>   balance between giving people the capabilities they need while helping
>   them avoid dangerous outcomes.

So I don't think it is possible using public API.

Comment: thanks for ur reply. It seems like the only solution is removing the minimize button ? :)

Comment: Yes @saji723, that is the wisest option. Apple is very strict about it, and no way your app pass the validation with a minimize button.

Comment: If there was a URL scheme to open the Springboard app (home screen) it would be possible to emulate pressing the home button I guess (can’t be sure it would look exactly like that).