# Hide/Minimize app on button tap

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton

In my app I want to minimize/hide my app when user presses an button. It it possible to hide or minimize app on UIButton tap? If so, how?

Comment: minimize? like go back to the home screen?

Comment: Yes. Minimize like back to home screen or lock screen.

Comment: Looks like this functionality is not the recommended one, [Check Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391784/how-to-minimize-an-ios-app?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not possible. You can put all kinds of functionality on `UIButton` clicks, but returning to the home screen is not a functionality that is available. Going back to the home screen after an action within the app could be interpreted as a crash.

This is what the home button is there for after all.