# Minimize and run an app in the background

Tags: ios, swift

Can an app go into background execution and minimize itself, but execute a code to perform a certain action (recording the screen to be specific) in iOS Swift.

Comment: Even if you can do it You are not able to post it into the Appstore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Programming Guide: Background Execution](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

This should help get you started. But you can't do what you want to do for longer than three minutes and you won't be able to put in on the app store.

Comment: Thanks for the link Asdrubal... I want to create the .ipa file of it. But just to know why cant I publish the app in the app store. Is it because I am recording the screen

Comment: You can do what you want, but it will only last for 3 minutes. You can't put it on the app store because it against the apple guidelines. I assume the reason for that guideline is that it waste battery. They do allow operations to occur in the background if they fit the criteria for example Navigation.

Comment: Ok..Thanks for these infos. But incase I want to run the app in background. Can I self minimize the app and display the home screen instead ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391784/how-to-minimize-an-ios-app?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: In the first case...does minimizing the app automatically takes it to background. Or it can still be kept in foreground ?

Comment: It would enter the background and you would call your background execution code. But the easiest thing would be to indicate to your users to press the home button.

Comment: If you think this was helpful I would appreciate being marked the answer

Comment: I want to minimize the app, and show an alert to let user know that they are being taken to the home screen...And in the meantime run a part of my code which records the user actions on the screen thereon.

Comment: You can't really do that directly. You can show an alert and in the alert message you can tell the user to press the home button. And when they press the home button the app will enter the background and then you can run your code. You won't be able to enter the background mode programmatically.

Comment: Okk..Atleast I have got something to try upon.. Let me work on it. Thnks fr d help Asdrubal.

Comment: No problem. Good luck :)