# How to force iOS app to backgorund

Tags: ios

I have an iOS app that disables the idleTImer while it performs a task. The idleTImer is restored if the user activates another app and then disabled again if the app is brought to the surface. After a period of time my app completes it's task. I want to force the app to enter the background "applicationDidEnterBackground" should fire.

How do I force my app to enter the background or suspend ?

Comment: You can't. That's in the user's control.

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8920844/force-app-to-close-and-run-in-background